# Piano methods (classical) that address musical meter specifically

Tags: piano, rhythm, meter

Czerny's op.500, book 1, lessons #12 and #13 are specifically about meter. I think the main point of the lessons is playing various rhythms which subdivide the beat while being able to count the meter properly.

Can anyone recommend other piano methods which use a similar approach?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but I think there is an important point to make. At this point in my studies, I was getting all of my examples from the standard literature. It's my strong opinion that exercise books like this be kept to a minimum, and not be used at all once someone is sufficiently advanced (such as they would be by the time they get to the specified Czerny examples).

Naturally, there are many etudes which cover rhythm. For example, Chopin's Etude No. 1 in F Minor from Trois Nouvelles Etudes is a good example of 3 over 4, and is a good piece to couple with the Fantasy Impromptu which has a lot of 4 over 3. I don't know that these 2 examples are what you are looking for in terms of meter, but the larger point is that method books are generally not worth the time when there are so many good examples in real music.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are looking for is accuracy in subdividing beats into 3,4,5,etc.  then it might be worth looking at the Scriabin Etudes.  They are not at all easy but there are lots of complex rythmic ideas there.